# Efficient way to select child records from a MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a mysql database. 
I created a table in this database that holds posts.

The table has the following columns:

```
p_id (primary key), post_header, creation_date, post_body, r_id, u_id
```

So each record represents a post.

`r_id` references a `p_id`, when it is not null it indicates that it is a reply to that `p_id` (or post id).

My issue is that I want a single query to grab all the posts and have all replies to each post grouped underneath.

Example Result Set:

[image: Result Set]

So basically I am looking for a query that can order my global posts by creation date desc, and also nest the replies underneath also in order by creation date desc.

I tried using the group by function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM global_post group by r_id order by creation_date desc;
```

but it doesn't work though. Is there a mechanism that can group records together like this?

I don't want to have to subquery for each post

Comment: you are almost there, consider looking at the `groub by` clause. That should help you.

Comment: I made a mistake in the query i used. Please see my edits, TNhe query i tried out was `SELECT * FROM global_post group by r_id order by creation_date desc;` I thought this would do the trick but im missing allot of rows when i do this. And it doesnt look correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is used for aggregating data, which is not what you want.

Try ordering by `coalesce(r_id, p_id)` which will give global posts the same order as their children. Then add a second ordering that puts the global_post on top with a case statement.

```
select * from global_post 
order by coalesce(r_id, p_id) desc, 
case when r_id is null then 0 else 1 end, creation_date desc
```

Comment: this is very very close to what i need, however when i try to order this query by creation_date desc, it breaks the order. I tried: ` select * from global_post order by coalesce(r_id, p_id), case when r_id is null then 0 else 1 end, creation_date desc`

Comment: this query lead me to the right answer. To order by desc i had to put desc after the coalesce function AND at the end: `select * from global_post 
order by coalesce(r_id, p_id) desc, case when r_id is null then 0 else 1 end, creation_date desc`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a trick on the order by section

```
order by Case when r_id is null then p_id else r_id end
```

Comment: it didnt work, whenever i use `group by r_id` it limits the result set to 2/17 records for some reason...

Comment: I don't believe that you need a group by. It is mostly an order issue.